# dispatcher not working from inside a Task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Short Story:
Why does this work (anonymous method inside a Task):

```
 Task.Run(() => MyMetod() );
```

but this does not work (same method invoked by a dispatcher)?

```
Task.Run(() => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MyMetod() ));
```

A step by step debug correctly enters the first method as expected but never enters the second one. Is there anthing needed before calling the InvokeAsynch method?

Context is a WPF application.

EDIT:
Long story:
In the end, I am just trying run a Window inside an asynch Task.
This window is created in the main thread, so I have to use a dispatcher inside the task.
I am noob to this all so there might be much easier ways to display this window:

Main thread:

```
     Window window = new Window();
    View view = new View();
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    window.Content = view;

... business stuff
```

At this point I want to open window and have the program to keep running:
window.ShowDialog() halts execution

window.Show(); returns imediatly

So I need to run window in a different tas via Task.Run:
 Task.Run(() => window.ShowDialog()));
will not work as window was created into a different stuff.

So I thought that the solution would look like:

```
Task.Run(() => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => window.ShowDialog() ));
```

But this causes the issue mentionned...

If I use await, the execution will wait for the task to terminate (meaning the user to close window).

Comment: Describe "not work". Try to prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I mean that a  step by step debug correctly enters the first method as expected but never enters the second one.

Comment: Don't do step-by-step, rather set a breakpoint inside `MyMethod` it should work in either case. It's unclear where you set breakpoint now and how exactly you do step-by-step debugging. If it's a problem of `Dispatcher` not working, then we need better context (mcve).

Comment: Why would you want to call the dispatcher from inside a task, instead of using `await`? If you are in the UI thread already, what you are trying to do is execute a function on the same UI thread as your currently executing code. Obviously, the method will block until your current code finishes executing

Comment: sorry, I gave more details in edit.

Comment: uh.. I don't see what you want to achieve.. you want to block the UI with a moda dialog, but you want the your code to not block on `ShowDialog`?

Comment: I just want to start a window from my man thread into a new thread. I want the window to stay open in the new thread while the main thread keeps running.